# PHPMailer - how to get the username at the time of sending in order to welcome him?

Tags: phpmailer

I want to send a message to the user through PHPMailer to get the user's login to greet him - `"Dear". $username. "!"`. How can i do this? Given that I used `$mail->addAddress($email, $username);` more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how you have your emails/usernames implemented but the basic answer is to use a for loop (or possibly a while loop depending on implementation). The following code assumes you have two arrays, one for emails and one for usernames and their indices are appropriately aligned.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($emails); $i++) {
  $message = "Dear ".$usernames[$i]."!";
  //Recipients
  $mail->addAddress($emails[$i]);     // Add a recipient

  //Content
  $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
  $mail->Subject = 'Hello!';
  $mail->Body    = $message;
  $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($message);

  $mail->send();
  $mail->ClearAllRecipients( );
}
```

The trick is to use `$mail->ClearAllRecipients( );` and then add the new recipient and their custom body/header.